# Calculating mean of means by groups with conditions in R

Tags: r, dataframe, grouping, data-manipulation

I have this data...

```
   Scientificname               Level Zone  levelmean
   <chr>                        <int> <chr>     <dbl>
 1 Acanthostracion polygonius       3 B         0.135
 2 Acanthostracion quadricornis     1 B         0.286
 3 Acanthostracion quadricornis     1 D         0.228
 4 Acanthostracion quadricornis     2 B         0.212
 5 Acanthostracion quadricornis     2 D         0.181
 6 Acanthostracion quadricornis     3 B         0.247
 7 Acanthostracion quadricornis     3 D         0.222
 8 Acanthostracion quadricornis     4 B         0.151
 9 Acanthostracion quadricornis     4 D         0.202
10 Acanthostracion spp.             2 B         0.225
11 Achirus lineatus                 1 B         0.204
12 Achirus lineatus                 1 D         0.202
13 Achirus lineatus                 2 B         0.219
14 Achirus lineatus                 2 D         0.181
15 Achirus lineatus                 3 B         0.145
16 Achirus lineatus                 3 D         0.172
17 Achirus lineatus                 4 B         0.135
18 Achirus lineatus                 4 D         0.142
```

```
structure(list(Scientificname = c("Acanthostracion polygonius", 
"Acanthostracion quadricornis", "Acanthostracion quadricornis", 
"Acanthostracion quadricornis", "Acanthostracion quadricornis", 
"Acanthostracion quadricornis", "Acanthostracion quadricornis", 
"Acanthostracion quadricornis", "Acanthostracion quadricornis", 
"Acanthostracion spp.", "Achirus lineatus", "Achirus lineatus", 
"Achirus lineatus", "Achirus lineatus", "Achirus lineatus", "Achirus lineatus", 
"Achirus lineatus", "Achirus lineatus"), Level = c(3L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L), 
    Zone = c("B", "B", "D", "B", "D", "B", "D", "B", "D", "B", 
    "B", "D", "B", "D", "B", "D", "B", "D"), levelmean = c(0.134916351861846, 
    0.286175876741544, 0.228368580556262, 0.21169261421555, 0.181497972824247, 
    0.247241190981072, 0.221534021013127, 0.151406128200516, 
    0.201513319317781, 0.224860586436409, 0.204040161766372, 
    0.201884774621553, 0.219239071775499, 0.18121539764963, 0.144981540016618, 
    0.172393116267914, 0.134916351861846, 0.141662169454938)), row.names = c(NA, 
-18L), groups = structure(list(Scientificname = c("Acanthostracion polygonius", 
"Acanthostracion quadricornis", "Acanthostracion quadricornis", 
"Acanthostracion quadricornis", "Acanthostracion quadricornis", 
"Acanthostracion spp.", "Achirus lineatus", "Achirus lineatus", 
"Achirus lineatus", "Achirus lineatus"), Level = c(3L, 1L, 2L, 
3L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L), .rows = structure(list(1L, 2:3, 
    4:5, 6:7, 8:9, 10L, 11:12, 13:14, 15:16, 17:18), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
"vctrs_vctr", "list"))), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), .drop = TRUE), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

These are species names, Discharge level (4 is lowest, 1 is highest), and CPUE (catch per unit effort, aka number of fish caught).

What I want to do is get a quantifiable measure of sensitivity to discharge. So the only way I could think to do it was take the difference between the values for each pair of levels of discharge for each species for each zone. For example for Acanthostracion quadricornis in zone B i would take the difference between group 1 and 2, 1 and 3, 1 and 4, 2 and 3, 2 and 4, and 3 and 4, then take the mean of all those values.

It becomes more complicated because I only want to do this for species that occur in at least 2 levels per zone. Also I have about 130 species and they vary how many levels they show up in for each zone.

My ideal output would be...

```
                Scientificname Zone Sensitivity
1 Acanthostracion quadricornis    B  0.06367512
2 Acanthostracion quadricornis    D  0.02399275
3             Achirus lineatus    B  0.05164523
4             Achirus lineatus    D  0.03447407
```

The values in the ideal output may have been rounded.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We could reshape to 'wide' format with `pivot_wider` and then use `combn` to get the pairwise difference and take the `mean` with `rowMeans`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
tmp <- df1 %>%
    filter(n() > 1) %>%
    ungroup %>%
    pivot_wider(names_from = Level, values_from = levelmean, values_fill = 0)
Sensitivity <- rowMeans(do.call(cbind, combn(tmp[-(1:2)], 2, 
     FUN = function(x) abs(x[1]-x[2]), simplify = FALSE)))
out <- tmp %>%
          select(1:2) %>%
          mutate(Sensitivity = Sensitivity)
```

-ouptutu

```
out
# A tibble: 4 x 3
  Scientificname               Zone  Sensitivity
  <chr>                        <chr>       <dbl>
1 Acanthostracion quadricornis B          0.0733
2 Acanthostracion quadricornis D          0.0268
3 Achirus lineatus             B          0.0520
4 Achirus lineatus             D          0.0316
```

---

Or without reshaping

```
library(purrr)
df1 %>% 
   filter(n() > 1) %>%
   ungroup %>% 
   nest_by(Scientificname, Zone) %>% 
   ungroup %>% 
   transmute(Scientificname, Zone, 
     Sensitivity = map_dbl(data,
     ~ mean(abs(combn(.x$levelmean, 2, FUN = \(x) x[1]- x[2])))))
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 4 x 3
  Scientificname               Zone  Sensitivity
  <chr>                        <chr>       <dbl>
1 Acanthostracion quadricornis B          0.0733
2 Acanthostracion quadricornis D          0.0268
3 Achirus lineatus             B          0.0520
4 Achirus lineatus             D          0.0316
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that when I take the differences between different levels i need to do absolute value.

Comment: Okay, but when i calculate this manually i get 
Acanthostracion quadricornis B 0.063675117

Comment: i did it in excel, I got the same starting values.  then there should be 6 group differences correct? i got....  "1-2" "1-3" "1-4" "2-3" "2-4" "3-4"                                                               
                        0.074483 0.038935 0.076963 0.035549 0.060287 0.095835  ... and the mean of those is 0.063675117

Comment: @Johnny5ish this is reprodcuible if you check `v1 <- c(0.286175876741544, 0.21169261421555, 0.247241190981072, 0.151406128200516 );v2 <- combn(v1, 2);mean(abs(v2[1,] -v2[2,]))
[1] 0.07330964`

Comment: cancel that, i manually calculated in excel and made a mistake. I found it. Thank you for your help!

Comment: I'm beginning to like base R even more than `tidyverse` :D

Comment: @AnoushiravanR yes, in many cases, `base R` is faster as it may not have the attribute dependency and further checks. e.g. `ave` is one function that is very fast.  Similarly, [`tabulate`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68604367/is-there-an-efficient-alternative-to-table/68605005#68605005) as it was benchmarked yesterday

Comment: Do you think it's a decent solution master?

Comment: @AnoushiravanR it looks fine to me.  You may use the `FUN` option in `combn`

Comment: @AnoushiravanR As I mentioned before also, nobody owes any other person.  It is your effort and time that pays off

Comment: Two others are `split.default` and also `combn` that doesn't have direct `tidyverse` equivalences. You can create their output but you have to spare some lines.

Comment: I owe you an others because you take their time to explain these materials for me and time is the most precious things you could give to someone else.

Comment: @AnoushiravanR there is a faster [`combnPrim`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26828301/faster-version-of-combn) but it is again a package function

Comment: And `outer` of course which I never used.

Comment: @AnoushiravanR `outer/expand.grid` does all possible combinations which we save in `combn`, thus `combn` may be more memory efficient as less number of combinations

Comment: Yes yes you are right. But I noticed we can also pass other functions to `outer`. Like in this question that people used `outer` to save some lines but mine is a bit more verbose: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67557239/accumulate-values-for-every-possible-combination-in-r/68601448#68601448.

Comment: Really love the second one without reshaping :)

Comment: @akrun Hey I messed one thing up, I didn't consider the scale differences of different species. So now the species that have hundreds of individuals have a much higher sensitivity number versus a species with only a few individuals. What I need now is to calculate the percent differences of the different pair combinations. I was also thinking that maybe instead of calculating all pairs (1-2, 1-3, 1-4, 2-3, 2-4, 3-4), maybe it would make more sense to just calculate the percent differences of 1-2, 2-3, and 3-4 and take the mean percent from those three percent differences. What do you think?

Comment: @Johnny5ish please consider to post as a new question

Answer (score 5):

Here is a **base R** solution for you:

```
do.call(rbind, lapply(split(df, ~ Scientificname + Zone, drop = TRUE), function(x) {
  if(nrow(x) >= 2) {
    combs <- as.data.frame(t(combn(x$Level, m = 2)))
    x[["Sensitivity"]] <- 
      mean(abs(mapply(function(a, b) {
        x$levelmean[x$Level == a] - x$levelmean[x$Level == b]
      }, combs$V1, combs$V2)))
    head(x, 1)[, -which(names(x) %in% c("Level", "levelmean"))]
  }
}))

# A tibble: 4 x 3
# Groups:   Scientificname [2]
  Scientificname               Zone  Sensitivity
  <chr>                        <chr>       <dbl>
1 Acanthostracion quadricornis B          0.0733
2 Achirus lineatus             B          0.0520
3 Acanthostracion quadricornis D          0.0268
4 Achirus lineatus             D          0.0316
```

Answer (score 4):

A `data.table` option using `combn`

```
setDT(df)[
  ,
  .SD[.N > 1],
  .(Scientificname, Zone)
][
  , 
  .(Sensitivity = mean(abs(combn(levelmean,2,diff))))
  ,
  .(Scientificname, Zone)
]
```

or a shorter one (since `df` is already a grouped data.frame)

```
setDT(df %>%
  filter(n() > 1))[
  , 
  .(Sensitivity = mean(abs(combn(levelmean,2,diff))))
  ,
  .(Scientificname, Zone)
]
```

gives

```
                 Scientificname Zone Sensitivity
1: Acanthostracion quadricornis    B  0.07330964
2: Acanthostracion quadricornis    D  0.02677209
3:             Achirus lineatus    B  0.05200446
4:             Achirus lineatus    D  0.03158168
```

Comment: Compact option with `data.table`

Comment: @akrun I just saw that `df` is a grouped data.frame. Your `filter(n()>1)` inspired me :)